# Does the community think that laws of physics work differently in enterprise and consumer-grade products?

Tags: discussion

It is not uncommon for questions on NE to focus on (or boil down to) the pure physics of how things work and just what they are. Examples:

- [How is data flow in a twisted pair cable?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73871/how-is-data-flow-in-a-twisted-pair-cable)
- [twisted pair vs single ended usb](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22742/twisted-pair-vs-single-ended-usb)
- [Is fiber optic Digital or analog? optical signal is digital or analog?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22676/is-fiber-optic-digital-or-analog-optical-signal-is-digital-or-analog)
- [Is the `twisted-pair` line transfer `digital data` and `ADSL` line transfer the `modulated electrical signal`?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53619/is-the-twisted-pair-line-transfer-digital-data-and-adsl-line-transfer-the)

Note that such questions are abstracted from the enterprise vs consumer-grade context (the things in question are used in both contexts, and everywhere). The person asking the question could have reasons for asking it coming from either context, or a totally different context e.g. engineering studies.

In such scenarios, does the actual context being home/consumer-grade disqualifies the question from being on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the [help center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> - physical infrastructure (e.g. standard color coding of cables, types of fiber, etc.)

is explicitly on-topic here. That is, as long as it's in an environment identical to or very close to

> - operating, maintaining, purchasing or managing an enterprise / service
>   provider network

If the question is about using damaged, out-of-spec or otherwise unsuited cabling, or off-topic equipment, then the question itself quickly becomes off-topic. The physics is the same of course, but there's only so much of that we can cover here.

Comment: "_as long as it's in an environment_" — so the environment matters, does it? If say I ask about "standard color coding of" some cables that people use in both enterprise and home environments, but incidentally _I_ use them in my home environment only, does that render the question off-topic?

Comment: @Greendrake, if you do not mention that it is a home network, then it may be an OK question. Consumer-grade equipment is off-topic, so if we need to know the equipment model and configuration, you have a problem. Also, the [help/on-topic] does mention other sites where a question may be on-topic, including, "_[electronics.se] for electronics and electrical engineering questions_" The questions you mention probably should have been asked there because it may be good background, but it really has nothing to do with what a network engineer does on the job; better questions about cable categories.